# Equivalent to 'where()' on custom attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know that with eloquent, when using `where()` like

```
$user = $user->where('age', 21);
```

it searches the database column. I need to be able to use something similar to `where`, but on a custom attribute. I know this is not actually do-able, i'm just looking for alternative solutions/suggestions.

I know I can create the data with a custom sql query so it does exist as a column and just use the where on that, but i'm creating a large filtering system so the SQL query would be far too complex.

Are there any solutions which are similar and can achieve the same thing as `where()` but with a custom attribute?

For example, in a perfect world this code would work

**model**

```
public function getFooAttribute(){
   if($this->age >= 21){
      return 'young-adult';
   }
}
```

**controller**

```
$user = $user->where('foo','young-adult')->get();
```

The questions i have seen are all before 2015, so I just want to know if there are any sort of solutions todays version of laravel?

Open to any suggestions.

Comment: why do you want to move the responsibility of filtering your data from the SQL phase to the PHP phase? can you imagine a table that have more than 20K row, and you are trying to fetch them all and after that performing your filtering in all of these 20K row?

Comment: Because the data I want to filter on does not exist in SQL, i am generating it in a custom attribute. I can get the same data in SQL, but as stated in the OP, the SQL query would be far to complex for how many filters I am applying

Comment: This will work `User::all()->>where('foo','young-adult')`, but `where()` for collections can have a very poor performance depending on how many users there are.

Answer (score 2):

The `where` operation is performed on the database via the query, but the custom attribute only exists on the model, which is populated after the database is queried. You might have better luck using a scope like e.g.:

```
function scopeAgeGroup($query, $ageGroup) {
     switch ($ageGroup) {
        case 'young-adult':
           $query->where('age', >, 21); 
           break;
         // More cases if needed
     }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$user->ageGroup('young-adult');
```

However this means that you will somehow need to manually keep your accessors and scope consistent. To help keep these consistent you can do something like:

```
 class User {
      private static $ageBreakdowns = [
            'young-adult' => [ 21, 35 ],
            'less-young-adult' => [ 36, 50 ],
            'less-less-young-adult' => [ 51, 100 ]
      ];


       public function getFooAttribute(){
            foreach (self::$ageBreakdowns as $groupName => $ageGroup) {
                 if ($this->age > $ageGroup[0] && $this->age <= $ageGroup[1]) {
                     return $groupName;
                 }
            }
            return 'really-young';
       }

       function scopeAgeGroup($query, $ageGroup) {
            if (array_key_exists($ageGroup, self::$ageBreakdowns) {
                  $query->whereBetween('age', self::$ageBreakdowns[$ageGroup]); 
            }                
       }
 }
```

Then you can also do:

```
$user->ageGroup('young-adult');
```

but you only need to modify the static array to change group names or age ranges.

Comment: I never thought about using scopes, i'll look into it this way. Thanks for the suggestion!